# Filter questions by keywords on python?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project that involves people asking questions about a certain text. What I´m looking for is a way to extract the keywords of the question to later search the text.

**Ex:**
Imagine that I have a text regarding Europe history and someone asks 'When was the French Revolution?'. Obviously If I looked for every single word in the question, a lot of results would come out. So, what I want is to filter just the words 'Frech Revolution'.

I thought of making a list of exceptions (such as 'where', 'when', 'what', etc) and just take the words away and make a new text. But, since questions are generally more complex, I would have to make a huge list with verbs and all that stuff.

Comment: If you want to start parsing actually natural language, you really should look into a dedicated library. [ntlk](http://www.nltk.org/) is the defacto natural-language processing library for Python.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks!